Определить битрейт видео в формате webm
sub.check_output("ffprobe -i /test_b200.webm -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1", shell=True).decode().strip().split('/')[0]

С файлами mp4 работает, показывает битрейт видео. Выполняю с файлом Webm туже операцию, ничего не отдает N/A.
У кого нибудь работает данная команда с файлом в расширении webm?
Второй вопрос, подскажите надежную утилиту которая надежно покажет битрейт вне зависимости от расширения...
Все же надеюсь, что при помощи ffprobe или ffmpeg. Возможно также надежно получать битрейт...
